# php8.2 how to use execute_query without opening multiple connections

Tags: php, mysqli

I jumped from PHP7.3 to PHP8.2 and looking for a "multiple_execute_query()" function to connect only one time to mysql and transmit a few queries but with execute_query() to prevent sql-injections. Is there a possibility to do that without looping and multiple connections?

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover I think they're looking for something that supports prepared statements.

Comment: There's never been much benefit to using multi-query instead of separate queries, and it makes processing the results more complicated.

Comment: Why would you need multiple connections? Just run execute_query() as many times as you need. You can use the same connection each time. You might need a loop, but so what?

Comment: I´ve heard that connecting multiple times is stressing the mysql-server?

Comment: Yes it does. But you don't need to connect multiple times, you just need to query multiple times, on the same connection

Comment: To be 100% clear: Running execute_query() does not open a new connection. It uses an existing connection, which must already be open.

Comment: Got it. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent of `multi_query` in mysqli which supports prepared statements.

But...running `execute_query()` does not open a new connection. It uses an existing connection, which must already be open. So you don't need to have any worries about calling that function multiple times (using a loop, for example).

Simple scenario:

```
//$conn is the connection object, which we create once, here. This opens the connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db, $port);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $j = $i*2;

  //here we execute the query many times, but always re-using the same connection object
  $conn->execute_query("UPDATE someTable SET someColumn = ? WHERE someOtherColumn = ?", [$j, $i]);
}
```